# How to get a TCP/IP packet over an serial connection (Bluetooth)

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, bluetooth, embedded

I'm developing an TCP/IP stack that will run on another device connected by bluetooth.

But I want to test against an working Stack. My testing scenario would be:

MY DEVICE TCP/IP STACK --------------BLUETOOTH ----------------- WINDOWS/MAC TCP/IP Stack.

Anyone have any idea how could I write IP packets over an Bluetooth connection on Linux/Windows or mac ??

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/papers/Wireless/Fairness/2000-TCP-over-blue-tooth.pdf

Comment: Bluetooth defines DUN, LAP, and PAN profiles.  Does at least one of them suit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

One way is you could establish a ppp connection between the device and the PC over bluetooth first. For this you will need support for ppp on the device side. Once you are able to dial-up and establish a ppp connection, tcp/ip can be run over ppp.

These links may be useful (although they are specific to linux):

http://www.daybefore.net/bluetooth_ppp.html

http://www.rpgameplace.de/blog/index.php?/archives/19-Networking-over-Bluetooth-using-BlueZPPP.html